# Runtime error even with error handling

Tags: c#, exception, asp.net-mvc-4

I've followed the following tutorial in regards to exception handling for my MVC4 project with razor syntax:
http://www.devcurry.com/2012/06/aspnet-mvc-handling-exceptions-and-404.html

After following it I still get runtime errors and thus the redirect to my error page doesn't happen when I for example enter an incorrect url.
When I do so the exception is logged and all and I pass through the methods I added with the tutorial but in the end it goes to the following page:

http://[ipadress]:9880/Error?aspxerrorpath=/test

and shows me:

```
Runtime Error

Description: An exception occurred while processing your request. Additionally, another exception occurred while executing the custom error page for the first exception. The request has been terminated.
```

The only major difference between the tutorial and my project is that I use an additional segment language.

I have the following code implemted for error handling.

in my routeConfig file:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "FailWhale",
            url: "{language}/FailWhale/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { language = "en-US", controller="Error" ,action = "FailWhale", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

In my filterConfig:

```
    public class HandleAndLogErrorAttribute : HandleErrorAttribute
    {
        public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
        {
            var exception = filterContext.Exception;
            var httpException = exception as HttpException;

            if (httpException != null) LogGateway.For(this).Fatal("Fatal Http exception occured --- " + httpException.Message);
            else LogGateway.For(this).Fatal("Fatal exception occured --- " + exception.Message);

            base.OnException(filterContext);
        }
    }
```

My web.config:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="Error">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="en-US/FailWhale" />
</customErrors>
```

My errorcontroller:

```
    public ActionResult FailWhale()
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 404;
        Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;

        LogGateway.For(this).Error("Fatal Http exception occured --- " + Response.StatusCode + ": " + Response.StatusDescription);

        return View();
    }
```

I'm probably overseeing something here?

Comment: I still haven't found a solution but it's seems that the problem is that it throws up two exceptions at the same time which is something that isn't handled correctly and causes the error page not to be shown. Anyone know of this and how to fix it?

Comment: Butting into this myself. Can be triggered by trying to open html tags in a url. e.g. `http://somehost.tld/<br`

Comment: More of a concern is that search engines are penalising us for 500 errors because other sites are linking to us badly. If you want to sabotage an asp.net mvc website, just create a bunch of bum links and get Google to index them. Grr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've linked my PC that runs the web site to a dyndns.org subdomain to test and found out that my issue is being handled correctly.